# email confirmation message after auto login

Tags: grails, spring-security, autologin

I am using grails 2.3.2 and spring security rc2 for authenication and able to have auto login and send confirmation email via following :

```
sendMail {
                from "somone@somthing.com.np"
                to params.user.username
                subject "Registration "
                body "You have register as following ID :"+institution.id+" \n" +
                        "Please click following link for verification "+
                        " \n"+baseURL+"/home/compare?code="+random+""
            }

 Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(params.user.username, params.user.password);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

but i need message to display at each page if the user has not clicked the confirmation link and if the user has clicked the confirmation email then the message should not appear.Is there any approach to do this please help...

Comment: What exactly is a problem? The action that processes the confirmation link can save any information to the user account. Then you can use it to distinguish users that are confirmed from the ones that are not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain conformStatus in User domain. set nullable :true.set boolean

when that url activate by the user, set true confirmationStatus in User domain.

In gsp,

```
<g:if test="{session.loggedInUser.confirmStatus== false}">
display like click confirmation link from your mail
</g:if>
```